# How to get user id from firebase auth as string?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm trying to insert data to firestore with the authenticated user id as the document id but i got null from the parameter.

Please take a look at my script.

```dart
void didChangeDependencies() {
  uid = '';
  super.didChangeDependencies();
}

Future _fetchUID() async {
  var auth = AuthProvider.of(context).auth;
  return await auth.getCurrentUser().then((user) => _uid = user.uid);
}

_validateAndSubmit() async {
  setState(() {
    _errorMessage = '';
    _isLoading = true;
  });

  if (_validateAndSave()) {
    try {
      _fetchUID();
      await Report.create(_uid, _suspectName, _plateNumber, _civilizationId,
          _drivingLicenseId, _clause, _description);
      return Navigator.of(context).pop();
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
        _errorMessage = e.message;
      });
      print(_errorMessage);
      throw Exception(e);
    }
  }
}
```

In this method below you can see that I have already tried to set the `_uid`, but I still cannot get the `_uid` value.

```dart
Future _fetchUID() async {
  var auth = AuthProvider.of(context).auth;
  return await auth.getCurrentUser().then((user) => _uid = user.uid);
}
```

This is how the `getCurrentUser()` method looks like.

```dart
Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser() async {
  FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
  return user;
}
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you mixed the `Future.then` syntax and the `async` `await` syntax.
You should probably write your method this way:

```dart
void _fetchUID() async {
  var auth = AuthProvider.of(context).auth;
  _uid = (await auth.getCurrentUser()).uid;
}
```

If `_uid` is still `null` for you after calling `_fetchUID` this way, then you are simply not signed in, meaning that there is no `FirebaseUser` as you first need to sign in.

In your `_validateAndSubmit` method, you also **first need to await** your `_fetchUID` call, otherwise it will pass `_uid` before it has been assigned a value.

```dart
...
try {
  await _fetchUID();
  await Report.create(_uid, ..);
  ...
```

Comment: it works, thanks for the answer and information. :)